# Haskell polymorphic array operations

Tags: arrays, haskell, polymorphism

I'm writing a bunch of different sorts and do this for lists and for arrays also. One thing that bothers me is that I can write a polymorphic sorting function for lists like

```
bubblesort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
```

but I when I try to do the same for `UArray`s:

```
alterUArray :: (Ix i, Ord e) => 
               (STUArray s i e -> ST s ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e
alterUArray alter ua = runST $ do
    mua <- thaw ua :: ST s1 (STUArray s1 i e)
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

it fails with [long error messages](http://hpaste.org/84907) from GHC (a version with `UArray Int Int` works well). I tried to specify `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, but this does not remove ambiguity of types `i e` in the `thaw` call. An error message without type of `thaw` : http://hpaste.org/84910.

What do I need to write a polymorhic `UArray` operation? Are there some fundamentional limitations? Are there compiler extensions which allow to do such things?

Comment: If you remove the type annotation from `thaw ua`, what error do you get then?

Comment: @dave4420 http://hpaste.org/84910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. First, as [dave4420 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15728164/1011995), `runST` needs the `alter` function to be polymorphic in the state `s`.

Fixing that, however, makes it impossible to solve the second problem, that you need an `MArray` instance for `thaw` (and `freeze`). You would need a constraint

```
alterUArray :: (Ix i, Ord e, IArray UArray e, forall s. MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => ...
```

to get it to work, since `runST` is the one to choose `s`. But you can't specify such a constraint.

If you give a specific element type (`Int`, `Double`, ...), it works since there is an

```
instance MArray (STUArray s) Int (ST s) where ...
```

so the demands of `thaw` and `freeze` are satisfied no matter what `s` is chosen by `runST` (and the constraint need not be stated).

It also works if you choose boxed arrays instead of unboxed ones, since there also is an

```
instance MArray (STArray s) e (ST s) where ...
```

and so there is no constraint on the element type that needs to be stated in the signature of `alterUArray`. (There is no constraint on the types of list elements, and list elements are boxed, so boxed arrays are the correspondence to lists, not unboxed arrays).

If you can bear getting your hands dirty, you can circumvent the problem by replacing `ST s` by `IO`,

```
alterUArray :: (Ix i, Ord e, MArray IOUArray e IO, IArray UArray e) =>
               (IOUArray i e -> IO ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e
alterUArray alter ua = unsafePerformIO $ do
    mua <- thaw ua
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

only needs `FlexibleContexts`. This allows to pass a bad `alter` argument that does nefarious `IO` stuff, though, and would hide it from the caller. So let us make the use of `unsafePerformIO` here safe, by forcing a more general type on the `alter` argument:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe

alterUArray :: forall i e. (Ix i, Ord e, IArray UArray e, MArray IOUArray e IO) =>
               (forall m u. MArray u e m => u i e -> m ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e
alterUArray alter ua = unsafePerformIO $ do
    mua <- thaw ua :: IO (IOUArray i e)
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

Now we have given `alter` a type that makes it impossible to do nefarious `IO` without itself using `unsafePerformIO`, so the use of `unsafePerformIO` here doesn't introduce additional insecurity - at the expense of more needed extensions.

(Note: while using `thaw` to get a copy of the original array is necessary, there is no need for an additional copy when freezing, that could be `unsafeFreeze` without a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

I was bothered by this kind of problems as well. Now I believe it is impossible to write such polymorphic function.

We can write

```
alterArray :: (Ix i, IArray b e, IArray a e, MArray a2 e m) => 
              (a2 i e -> m a1) -> a i e -> m (b i e)
alterArray alter ua = do
    mua <- thaw ua 
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

Or

```
alterUArrayST :: (Ix i, IArray UArray e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => 
                 (STUArray s i e -> ST s ()) -> UArray i e -> ST s (UArray i e)
alterUArrayST alter ua = do
    mua <- thaw ua 
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

But if we want to get rid of `ST`, we have to write some type specific versions, e.g.

```
alterUArrayInt :: (forall s. STUArray s Int Int -> ST s ()) -> UArray Int Int -> UArray Int Int
alterUArrayInt alter ua = runST $ do
    mua <- thaw ua 
    alter mua
    freeze mua

alterUArrayFloat :: (forall s. STUArray s Int Float -> ST s ()) -> UArray Int Float -> UArray Int Float
alterUArrayFloat alter ua = runST $ do
    mua <- thaw ua 
    alter mua
    freeze mua
```

If `MArray` had an instance `MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)`, I think we could write such polymorphic function. Unforunately, `MArray` doesn't have no such instance.

yairchu gave another workaround for this kind of problems in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244281/779412.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type declaration to

```
alterUArray :: (Ix i, Ord e) => 
               (forall s. STUArray s i e -> ST s ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e
```

and get rid of the type annotation from `thaw ua`.

You'll need to enable the `RankNTypes` extension (or `Rank2Types`, though that's deprecated) (but don't you need to do that anyway to use `runST`? I forget).

Explanation: your original type declaration is equivalent to

```
alterUArray :: (Ix i, Ord e) => 
               forall s. (STUArray s i e -> ST s ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e
```

Which means that `alterUArray`'s caller gets to choose what `s` is. My changed type insists instead that `alterUArray` gets to choose itself what `s` is. Your code then defers the choice of `s` to `runST`; its type insists that it gets to make the choice.

Comment: I tried to specify more context by changing type signature to `(Ix i, Ord e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => (forall s1. STUArray s1 i e -> ST s1 ()) -> UArray i e -> UArray i e `, does not work either.

Comment: Cale on #haskell IRC suggested this: `alterUArrayST :: forall i e s. (Ix i, IArray UArray e, MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => (STUArray s i e -> ST s ()) -> UArray i e -> ST s (UArray i e)`

Comment: @EarlGray Did Cale's answer fix it for you? If not, which modules are you importing?

Comment: Yes, it compiles with `RankNTypes, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables`, but (as he cautioned) application of this function to others is still a lot of type-matching work.